# Can I use Java 8 syntax in Java EE 7 projects?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8

Sorry for this stupid beginner's question but I wasn't able to get a clear answer for that:

Can I use lambdas, method pointers, streams etc. in a Java EE 7 project? Does this have any negative consequences or is this very difficult/error-prone to setup on a existing project?

I come from a C# background so I find it very hard to get back to Java 7 syntax with anonymous classes for runnables/callables and no replacement for LINQ like streaming etc. so this would be a huge help.

Many thanks,
spyro

Comment: If you are using Java 8, then yes you can use Java 8 syntax. Java EE is essentially only a framework specification (implemented by your application server) and runs on top of the Java VM you are using.

Comment: You have to check which JDK is supporting your application server. If you have access to the server running your application server, you can have a look at the running processes to check which JDK is being used.

Answer (score 9):

From a Java EE point of view, the [Java EE 7 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-eval-spec/JavaEE_Platform_Spec.pdf) requires at least Java SE 7. So clearly, nothing prevents you from using Java SE 8 with Java EE 7. For more details, have a look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_se_8_and_java).

Some popular Java EE 7 containers like GlassFish, WildFly and Apache TomEE are Java SE 8 compatible. So there's nothing that prevents you from using Java SE 8 features in Java EE 7 applications.